# Упрощение когда js

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток!!
Написал код http://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/MUCbF/ , тут список размеров и список цветов, под каждый размер свой массив цветов, и при клике на определённый размер определяется какие цвета есть и выводит их, я тут реализовал событие клик для каждого размера по отдельности то есть беру `id`, ну и соответственно в `for` я подрубаю нужный массив. Как упростить код так, чтобы при клике на размер была проверка или что-то вроде того, чтобы подрубался нужный мне массив. То есть к примеру я беру

```
$('colors_tr2 li').click(function(){});
```

При нажатии на любой из `li` размеров мне в `for` подключался нужный массив?
если что-то не понятно пишите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, [вот так](http://jsfiddle.net/MUCbF/5/).

Comment: Все просто супер,Спасибо +1.

Answer (score 4):

Ну упрощать, так упрощать!)

Сперва я бы сделал массив, удобный для понимания:

```
var size_colors = {
   's':['green','purple','blue','brown'],
   'm':['green','purple','blue','brown','blue2','green2'],
   'l':['green','purple','brown','blue2','green2'],
   'xl':['blue','brown','blue2','green2'],
   'xxl':['green','purple','blue','brown','blue2','green2']
}
```

Потом переписал бы событие `click`:

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    var colors = size_colors[$(this).data('size')];

    /**
     * скрываем все li
     */
    $(".colors_tr li").css('display','none');
    /**
     * показываем все li, у которых класс совпадает с тем классом, 
     * что есть в массиве этого размера
     */
    $(".colors_tr").find('li.'+colors.join(',li.')).css('display','block');
});
```

И в `html` коде к каждой ссылке добавил атрибут `data-size`, в котором указывал нужный размер.